# Weird behaviour with IntelC++ 15.0(on Linux) with typedefs and SFINAE

Tags: c++, linux, typedef, sfinae, icc

Recently I wanted to shift from g++ to IntelC++ compiler hoping for better performance but instead I was getting all sorts of compiler errors. I dug a little deeper and noticed this weird behaviour of IntelC++ compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct B {};

template<typename T>
struct A
{
  operator std::string() const
  {
    return "testing";
  }
};

typedef A<B> C;

template<typename T>
struct SupportsStringOperator
{
  typedef char Yes;
  typedef Yes No[2];

  template <typename U, U> struct has;

  template <typename Fun>
  static Yes& fun_test(has<std::string (Fun::*)() const, &Fun::operator std::string>*);

  template <typename Fun>
  static Yes& fun_test(has<std::string (Fun::*)(), &Fun::operator std::string>*);

  template<typename>
  static No& fun_test(...);

  static const bool value = (sizeof(fun_test<T>(0)) == sizeof(Yes));
};

int main()
{
  A<B> a;
  cout << std::is_same<C, A<B>>::value << endl;
  cout << SupportsStringOperator<C>::value << endl;
  cout << SupportsStringOperator<A<B>>::value << endl;
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
1
0
0
```

Only if you change the main function to -

```
int main()
{
  A<B> a;
  cout << std::is_same<C, A<B>>::value << endl;
  cout << SupportsStringOperator<A<B>>::value << endl;
  cout << SupportsStringOperator<A<B>>::value << endl;
}
```

The output will be -

```
1
1
1
```

Is there a rational behind this behaviour? g++ and clang++ produces the second output for both the codes.

Comment: slightly off-topic where can I get that compiler ( also is it free of cost for trial ) so that I could also reproduce that problem.

Comment: What's wrong with just using `is_convertible`?

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal You can get the compiler from https://software.intel.com/en-us/qualify-for-free-software for free, if you are a student or open-source contributor

Comment: @T.C. I don't understand. why do I need is_convertible? A<B> and C are same types. Which can be seen with `std::is_same`. Hence both the codes are one and the same. Or I think they are same

Comment: I mean using `is_convertible` instead of your custom-written trait.

Comment: @T.C.  ahh.. Sorry for the confusion. I agree is_convertible will make the code little easier, but it still does not explain the behaviour shown by IntelC++. This is just part of my original code.